# How to prove Dense Subgraph problem is in NP

Tags: np-complete, np

I have been studying NP-Complete problems and I saw the Dense Subgraph problem. Then I saw that they are trying to show that the problem is NP (see below quote), but I can't understand how it verifies that time is polynomial.

> Problem: Dense Subgraph
>
> Input: A graph $G$, and integers $k$ and $y$.
>
> Output: Does $G$ contain a subgraph with exactly $k$ vertices and at least $y$ edges?
>
> To prove Dense Subgraph is NP-complete, we show that Dense Subgraph is in NP and is NP-hard by reducing CLIQUE problem to Dense Subgraph.
>
> Dense Subgraph is NP: the polynomial time verifier will take $(G,k,y)$ and $H = (V', E')$ as certificate and check if $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, $|V'| = k$, $|E'| \geq y$.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that that doesn't prove the algorithm is polynomial, as it just gives the certificate. But it is very easy to see that (for example with a program in a C-like language, given a reasonable representation of  the graphs) the check is very easy to do (is polynomial).

The part of coming up with a polynomial verifier given a reasonable certificate (i.e., proof that the problem is in $\mathsf{NP}$) is usually easy, and left as an exercise for the gentle reader.

Comment: I understand, thanks!